# svn cannot svn mkdir a file under my repository

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I have setup a svn repository on my server. I, instead of delete the directory under the repository, used rm -rf to delete the directory. Now that I cannot create any directory under my server, even when I deleted subversion and reinstall it. This is what I got.

```
root@skynet2012:/webserver/repos# svn mkdir file:///webserver/repos/blahblah

Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
c
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/webserver/repos/db', transaction '2-2', path '/blahblah'
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking.  What folder did you delete?  blahblah from your working copy?  Or something else?  Judging from the error message, your `svn mkdir` command is failing because the directory already exists.  If you suspect the repository has issues, check it with `svnadmin verify`.

Comment: blahblah is my working copy. Originally, I have created a working copy and deleted it with rm -rf because I wanna create a new working copy. Blahblah is my new working copy.

Comment: This is what I got from svnadmin verify     server@skynet2012:/webserver/repos$ ls
conf  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt
server@skynet2012:/webserver/repos$ svnadmin verify repos
svnadmin: Can't open file 'repos/format': No such file or directory
server@skynet2012:/webserver/repos$

Comment: Again, that's confusing.  You obtain a working copy with `svn checkout`, not with `svn mkdir`.  As your `svnadmin verify` command, you need to provide the path to the top of the repo.  If you're already in the repo, which your prompt suggests, it would look more like `svnadmin verify .`, not `svnadmin verify repos`, because the latter doesn't exist (which is what the command is trying to say).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to svn. Dose "working copy" refer to my local files? If so, I am sorry. Everything that I described above is happening on my server. I used svnadmin create to create repos under webserver, and tried to create a folder under repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory still exists in your repository. That is what the error says.

So all you need is a way to get it back in your working copy.

The easiest ways to do this are 
(Subversion 1.7 or later)

```
svn revert -R DIR
```

Which will revert all local changes on DIR.

Or
(All Subversion versions)

```
svn update DIR
```

Which will first bring back everything it can from the working copy and then update your working copy to the latest version.

Before Subversion 1.7 the data was stored per directory in a `.svn` subdirectory so a plain revert couldn't fix everything.

Comment: I have a new problem. I have editted my svnserve.conf, passwd and authz files, but I am still getting svn: '.' is not a working copy. However, I have gone ahead and import my files into the folder and made a checkout on my Mac. Everything is working well. Files were able to import into the repository, but when I tried to commit it shows "Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow): svn: Can't open file '/webserver/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied"

Comment: Subversion is driving me crazy. I have been working on this problem for a week now and still could not solve it. I have tried to uninstall subversion, deleted every files. Is there a way that I can start from fresh?